# how can i implement two step registration with phone number in django?

Tags: python, django, authentication, two-step-verification

I'm trying to make a [django](https://www.djangoproject.com/) app that needs to implement two-step registration with phone number and i searched for it and i did not find a useful result.

I have this idea that take a phone number and then generate random hash URL then redirect them into it for registration. is that good implementation?

and if you have a better idea for doing this please help me.

and sorry for my bad English.

Comment: could you please add your code whatever you have done so far

Comment: i don't have any implementation for this in my project.
just i want new idea for how do that.